# Will Windows 2008 R2 still accept remote connections if the system drive is full?

Tags: windows, rdp

I have a 2008 R2 server which is running out of system disk space. 
I know back with Windows 2003 server, if you ran out of disk space, RDPing into said server would often fail or freeze, resulting in one needing to make a trip to the server room (or use remote hands).

In anticipation of no free space on the system drive;
I want to know if Windows 2008 R2 will still accept remote RDP connections?

Things I have tried:
I have not tried filling up the server's system drive (grin) to see what happens.

Comment: Please read [this link](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include examples of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows still lets you log in through RDP if the system drive is full.

Comment: May not work reliably, but yeah, it'll let you login.  Or it'll let you try, at least.

Comment: It will let you log in. At least with a temporary profile. Would be devastating for all these Azure VM's and whatnot if you can't get to it remotely when the system drive is full. Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: I've also seen the login process crash and fail, presumably because it can't write tempfiles, so just pointing out that it might not work reliably.

Comment: OK, never had trouble before with that. Good catch then.

Comment: Thanks, I am managing a client's server and the client is putting off upgrade their hardware (running out of system disk space), so I just need to ensure that if they do run out space I can get into the server without having to go into the hosting company. Thanks for the answers.